# I want to extract missing digits from the input integer, using while/for loop ONLY

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

This is the output:

> Enter an integer: 123
>   Missing digits  : 0 4 5 6 7 8 9

```
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    while ( m > 0 ) {
        if(m % 10 == k) {
            m = m / 10;
            found = true;
        } else if( m% 10 != k) {
            found = false;
            m = m / 10;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
        cout << k << " ";
}
```

This is what i get as my output instead

> Enter an integer: 123
>   Missing digits  : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Might be easier to convert it to a string and check each character

Comment: print the value of `m` in the for loop and you will know what happen

Comment: This seems like a homework problem ... but it's probably easier if you separate it into the digits and create a set of those digits and intersect that with a 0-9 digit set. But if you print out what's going on you'll likely see why it ends up printing out what it does ... hint ... I hope you watch your `m` value.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, one way we can write the logic in this way

```
**$enteredInput = 123;

$enteredInputArray = str_split($enteredInput);

$missing = [];

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    if( !in_array($i, $enteredInputArray) )
        $missing[] = $i;
}

echo $missing;**
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are having problems with your program, it helps to step through it with a debugger or print the results of each step to the screen. I'll convert your code to JavaScript so you can run it here.

```html
<script>
var m=123
for(var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
   console.log("checking " +k);
    while ( m > 0 ) {
        console.log("m = " + m);
        if(m % 10 == k) {
            console.log("m % 10 = " + k);

            m = m / 10;
            found = true;
        } else if( m % 10 != k) {
            console.log("m % 10 != " + k);
            found = false;
            m = m / 10;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
       console.log("Didn't find " + k);
        //cout << k << " ";
     }
}

</script>
```

Looking at the output your issue becomes apparent:

```
checking 0 
m = 123 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 12.3 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 1.23 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 0.123 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 0.0123 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 0.00123 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 0.000123 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 0.0000123 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 0.00000123
m % 10 != 0 
m = 1.23e-7 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 1.2300000000000001e-8
m % 10 != 0 

.... Abbreviated, skipping ahead 312 checks.

m = 1.23e-320 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 1.23e-321 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 1.24e-322 
m % 10 != 0 
m = 1e-323 
m % 10 != 0 
Didn't find 0 
checking 1 
Didn't find 1 
checking 2 
Didn't find 2 
checking 3 
Didn't find 3 
checking 4 
Didn't find 4 
checking 5 
Didn't find 5 
checking 6 
Didn't find 6 
checking 7 
Didn't find 7 
checking 8 
Didn't find 8 
checking 9 
Didn't find 9
```

You also have other logical errors and there are more efficient ways to run this loop:

```
var ints = [];// in c you would use an array of bool
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
    ints[i]=false; 

var m=123;
while (m>0)
{
     console.log("checking " + m);
     var res= m % 10;
     m = Math.floor(m/10);
     ints[res]=true;
}
var found = "";
var notfound = "";
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if (ints[i])
        found += i + " ";
    else
        notfound += i + " ";
}
console.log(found);
console.log(notfound);
```

Output:

```
checking 123 
checking 12 
checking 1 
1 2 3  
0 4 5 6 7 8 9
```